# Arch Linux shows white terminal with xfce4 environment

Tags: archlinux

Installed arch Linux recently, the installation was fine but after logging in white terminal with black back ground appears. I am using xfce4 environment.

This is how it looks after logging in.

[image: photo of screen]

Comment: OK, is that good or bad? Were you expecting something else to happen? I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: It's suppose to be in GUI, not a plain white terminal.

Comment: That looks like a GUI (running a terminal emulator) to me. Your question is better suited to https://superuser.com/; StackOverflow is for programming problems.

Comment: From the ouput it seems u have only installed xorg u need to have some sort of Desktop environment installed ie. Xfce4,Mate,Gnome etc There are many tutorials on google search showing in detail process of setting up full arch installation.